# Making a caption only label in the table of figures

Tags: graphics, table-of-contents, floats

I am trying to figure out how to make a caption only appear in the List of Figures and not add any space below the figure. I am trying to include two pictures on each page and they are already getting small -- I want to include a list at the beginning of the document, but the added caption is pushing them onto an additional page. Here's an example (I know it's a picture):

[image: Image with a caption of "Figure 4"]

The code being used to create this is

```
    \begin{figure}
        \begin{center}
            \includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{Graphics/_FullSeries/k100CleanNoLegend.png}
            \caption[Full Series $k=100$]{}
        \end{center}
    \end{figure}
```

I already know about the trick with the brackets as the list item in the List of Figures and the required argument being blank. I also tried using the caption package with `\caption*{}`, but then it doesn't appear at all in the List of Figures. Any thoughts?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
\begin{figure}
    \begin{center}
        \includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{Graphics/_FullSeries/k100CleanNoLegend.png}
 %       \caption[Full Series $k=100$]{}
        \addcontentsline{lof}{figure}{Full Series $k=100$}
    \end{center}
\end{figure}
```

which will add `Full Series $k=100$` with the page number to the LoF and no caption below the figure (and no numbering); any fragile commands in the `Full Series $k=100$` text must be `\protect`ed.. Among other places the LaTeX macro `\addcontentslineline` is described in the `tocloft` (`<texdoc tocloft`) package.

But my question is: If there are two or more figures on a page how will the reader know which one is being referred to?